# Request de um formulário com laravel não funcionando

Tags: php, html, laravel, orientação-a-objetos, formulário

Estou fazendo um request do meu controller para um formulário na view, está dando esse erro. Tentei vários métodos, mas nenhum resolveu.

[image: Estou fazendo um request do meu controller para um formulário na view, está dando esse erro.]

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $NomeDaEmpresa = $request->input('NomeDaEmpresa');
    $nCompartilhamentos = $request->input('nCompartilhamentos');
    $valorPorShare = $request->input('valorPorShare');
    $eMail = $request->input('email');

    //Preco a pagar sem a taxa
    $PrecoaPagarST = $nCompartilhamentos * $valorPorShare;
    //Preco a pagar com a taxa (20%)
    $PrecoaPagarTotal = $PrecoaPagarST * 1.20;

    return view('EnviarAnuncio');
  }
 }
```

Formulário:

```html
<form role="form" action="/enviaranuncio" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome da empresa</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Digite o nome da empresa" type="text" value="" name="NomeDaEmpresa">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="exampleInputPassword1">Número de compartilhamento desejado</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Número de shares" type="text" value="" name="nCompartilhamentos">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Valor por share a pagar</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Valor a pagar por share. Ex: 0.10" value="" name="valorPorShare">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">E-mail</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Digite seu email" name="email" value="">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Criar Anúncio</button>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sempre que você definir um form tem de passar o token CSRF para o Laravel poder validar o pedido.

Assim, adicione o seguinte depois da tag `<form>`:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Mais info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf

Answer (score 2):

Pode adicionar o pacote Collective HTML[https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html].

E substituir o `<form>` por {!! Form::open() !!}, que já adiciona o input de _token.